# How to select table elements by column first with js/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following table:

```
====|=====|=====|=====|
 0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     1
 1     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0
```

Tables in HTML are defined by rows and then columns. Thus the index of the elements selected with javascript also follow that order. So if I select all number '1's and put them in a loop. The first element selected will be the first '1' in the first row.

How would I go about selecting the first 1 in the first column, assuming that '1' can be anywhere in that column (one per column)? And then move to the second column and find the second number '1'?

Here's the loop that selects by rows:

```
//All '1's have a .one class
$("tr td.one").each(function(){});
```

============ UPDATE =============

@Alex Char answer is correct. I modified it a little so that it would work for what I am trying to achieve. He's how I ended up using his solution:

```
var all_ones = [];

$(".one").each(function(){

   //Loop through all 1s get the td index and it's parent (tr) index.
   all_ones.push([$(this).index(),$(this).parent().index()]);

});

//Sort all_ones by the td index
all_ones.sort(function(a, b) {

   return a[0] - b[0];

});

//Loop throught the sorted index and print whatever                       
for(var i=0;i < all_ones.length;i++){

   $("table tr:eq(" + all_ones[i][1] + ") td:eq(" + all_ones[i][0] + ")").css({color:"red"});

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to select a row based on which column contains a `1`?

Comment: No. I am asking how to select in a way that the results are by column and not by row. So if I select all number 1s, the first one found would be in the first column and not in the first row->column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [.sort()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) like:

```js
var cells = $('table td').sort(function(a, b) {
  //compare the cell index
  var c0 = $(a).index();
  var c1 = $(b).index();
  if (c0 == c1) {
    //compare the row index if needed
    var r0 = $(a).parent().index();
    var r1 = $(b).parent().index();
    return r0 - r1;
  } else
    return c0 - c1;
});

//console.log(cells);
cells.each(function() {
  if ($(this).html() == "1") {
    $(this).css("background", "red");
  }
  document.write($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class="one">1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class="one">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class="one">1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*.sort() is not officially part of jquery.

**References**

[**.sort()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you. I believe you are asking is how to loop through the columns one at a time instead of the rows. If this is not correct, please correct me.

To look, you would do something akin to:

```
var onesInRows = [];
for(var i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++){
    onesInRows.push($('tr') //get all table rows
                         .find('td.one:nth-child('+i+')'))
                            //get the tds,
                            //that have class one,
                            //that are in the row you are currently selecting
}
```

The the first one in the first row would be:

```
onesInRows[0].eq(0);
```

First one in the second row would be:

```
onesInRows[1].eg(0);
```

Does that all make sense?

Update: and if you want all the ones in a single jQuery object:

```
var onesInAllRows;
for(var i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++){
    var onesInRow = ($('tr') //get all table rows
                         .find('td.one:nth-child('+i+')'))
                            //get the tds,
                            //that have class one,
                            //that are in the row you are currently selecting
    if(onesInAllRows.length !== 0){
       onesInAllRows.add(onesInRow);
    }
    else{
       onesInAllRows = onesInRow;
    }
}
```

Comment: This get's me the first one in the first row. However I need to loop through the first one in the first column, then the first one in the second column, then the first one in the third column...

Comment: If `numberOfColumns` is the number of Columns, it should get all the ones in all the rows. If you just want the first one in each row, add `.first()` to the end of the selector in the first code snippet (inbetween the 2 `)`s )

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nth-child selector [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) like this:

```
$( "tr td.one:nth-child(1)" )
```

this will give you all the td marked with class one in the first column if you only want the first you can use

```
$( "tr td.one:nth-child(1)" ).first()
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96uhu2q1/)